# Voting-system wont pass on vote to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, voting, voting-system

I'm having difficulties on debugging why this voting-script I'm trying to adapt wont update the vote count and register the user's IP-address in the database. As of now neither of the two things seem to be working.

The script consists of:

**Index.php**:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$(".vote").click(function() 
{

var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
var parent = $(this);


if(name=='up')
{

$(this).fadeIn(200).html('');
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "up.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,

   success: function(html)
   {
    parent.html(html);

  }  });

}
else
{

$(this).fadeIn(200).html('');
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "down.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,

   success: function(html)
   {
       parent.html(html);
  }

 });


}




    });

});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#main{
height:auto;
margin:0 auto;
width:500px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.clearfix{
clear:both;
}
#left{
float:left;
width:40px;
height:auto;
text-align:center;
}
#message{
float:right;
width:460px;
height:auto;
margin-top: 14px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
}
.up{
background-image:url(up.png);
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
      ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include('config.php');
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$message=$row['msg'];
$mes_id=$row['mes_id'];
$totalvotes=$row['totalvotes'];
?>
<div id="main">
    <div id="left">
    <span class='up'><a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $mes_id; ?>" name="up"><img src="up.png" alt="Down" /></a></span><br />
    <?php echo $totalvotes ?><br />
    <span class='down'><a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $mes_id; ?>" name="down"><img src="down.png" alt="Down" /></a></span>
    </div>
    <div id="message">
        <?php echo $message ?>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And **up.php** and **down.php**  that is similar except from the add/subtract part in the sql command.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set('display_errors', '1');

include("config.php");


$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

$id=$_POST['id'];
$id = mysql_escape_String($id);

$ip_sql=mysql_query("SELECT ip_add FROM voting_ip WHERE mes_id_fk='$id' AND ip_add='$ip'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($ip_sql);

if($count==0)
{
$sql = "UPDATE messages SET totalvotes=sum(totalvotes+1) WHERE mes_id='$id'";
mysql_query($sql);

$sql_in = "INSERT INTO voting_ip (mes_id_fk,ip_add) VALUES ('$id','$ip')";
mysql_query($sql_in);



}
else
{
}

?>
```

Online link here: http://itu.dk/people/mbaj/dwdeksamen/voting/voting/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any entry in the apache error log ?

Comment: Try some echo debugging and you will find where the problem is.. you can't just say "it doesn't work". Print out some variables, see what is going on.

Comment: I don't think I have access to it since I'm working on my school's server.

Comment: Does the up.php and down.php work by themselves?

Comment: Also change the update to "UPDATE messages SET totalvotes=totalvotes+1 WHERE mes_id='$id'"

Comment: They do, except from the $id, which is supposed to be passed from index.php: http://itu.dk/people/mbaj/dwdeksamen/voting/voting/up.php

Also, the IP gets passed to the DB now.